# How can I put each model City&Prefecture&Area&User?

Tags: python, django

I wanna put data of list to City&Prefecture&Area&User model ?
I wrote

```
book3 = xlrd.open_workbook('./data/excel1.xlsx')
sheet3 = book3.sheet_by_index(0)

data_dict = OrderedDict()
tag_list = sheet3.row_values(0)
tag_list1_user_id = tag_list[9]
fourrows = []
for row_index in range(7, sheet3.nrows):
    row = sheet3.row_values(row_index)
    if len(fourrows) == 5:
        fourrows=[]
    fourrows.append(row)
    fourrows_transpose = list(map(list, zip(*fourrows)))
    print(fourrows_transpose)
    val3 = sheet3.cell_value(rowx=0, colx=9)
    user3 = Companyransaction.objects.filter(user_id=val3)
    if user3:
       user3.update(XXXXX)
```

models.py is

```
class Area(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='エリア名', null=True)
class User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    area = models.ForeignKey('Area',null=True, blank=True)

class Prefecture(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='prefecture')
    area = models.ForeignKey('Area', null=True, blank=True)

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='city')
    prefecture = models.ForeignKey('Prefecture', null=True, blank=True)

class Price(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='price')
    PRICE_RANGE = (
        ('a', 'u500'),
        ('b', '500-1000'),
        ('c', 'u1000'),
    )
    price_range = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=PRICE_RANGE)
    city = models.ForeignKey('City', null=True, blank=True)
```

In print(fourrows_transpose),it is shown

```
[['America', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', 'u1000', '500～1000', 'd500'], ['NY', 'City A', '×', '×', '×'], ['', 'City B', '×', '×', '×'], ['', 'City C', '×', '×', '×'], ['', 'City D', '×', '×', '×'], ['', 'City E', '×', '×', '×']]
```

I wanna put 'America' to Prefecture's `area` and City A to City's `name` and ×　to Price's name .
So,i wanna put these data tp user3.update(XXXXX).What should I write to XXX?How can I do it?

Comment: do you have existing instances of Prefecture, City, and Price? Or you want to create new ones and link them to this user?

Comment: @N.Ivanov I wanna create new ones and link them to this user.

Comment: check my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have existing instances of Prefecture, City, and Price then you have to call each one and update separately.

**Example** (assuming that a User and a Prefecture are linked by the area property)**:**

```
pref = Prefecture.objects.get(area=user3.area)
city = City.objects.get(prefecture=pref)
price = Price.objects.get(city=city)

pref.name = "whatever you want"
pref.save()

city.name = "whatever you want"
city.save()

price.name = "whatever you want"
price.save()
```

If you do NOT have existing instances of the said above models, then you have to create an instance for each one, and link them to each other.

**Example** (assuming that a User and a Prefecture are linked by the area property)**:**

```
pref = Prefecture.objects.create(name="yourname", area=user3.area)
city = City.objects.create(name="yourname", prefecture=pref)
price = Price.objects.create(name="yourname", city=city)
```

Hope this helps!